# Brave browser: I'm getting 'Redirect Notice' from Google Calendar links on my new laptop but not on the older one

Tags: google-chrome, brave

I bought a new laptop and I'm using both right now, the new one and the old one.

I'm using Brave browser. Today, when I clicked on some links on my Google Calendar, they show me a 'Redirect Notice' alert, so I have to click again to going the url. I thought that it's something new on Google Calendar. But, then, I went to my old laptop and there the links works perfectly without the 'Notice'. I checked and I don't have any installed extension about this. So, I assume it's because is there any config option on Brave to avoid it. But I can't find it!! How can I force the redirect without the 'Notice'?

I put this link on the Calendar details field: `https://www.example.org`. But, when I save it and click on that event, I checked the links and they are converted on something like this on both computers:

`https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.example.org&sa=D&source=calendar&usd=2&usg=AOvVaw2KfUk444lrbI4wNV7rekh5`

On the old one, when I click on the link, I get a blank page with the text: 'Redirecting to https://example.org' and it does the redirect without asking confirmation:

[image]

On the new one, when I click on the link, I get also the same page, but this time, It's a 'Redirect Notice' for the redirection and I have to confirm it:

[image]

I have been doing some testing and not all urls show Redirect Notice on the new computer. Only some of them. Like the one in the picture.

I have updated Brave browser on both computers. They're using the same version.

These are both computers characteristics (but I don't think this information is related with my problem):

- **Old Laptop**: Microsoft Go 2. OS: Windows 11.
- **New Laptop**: Asus Zenbook. OS: Windows 11.

Comment: Please edit your question: What models are the laptops? Old and new? What OS do they run on? Old and new. More specifics can help us better help you solve this issue.

Comment: Give also an example of old and new URLs, before and after the redirection. The URL you show is just a query, it doesn't help.